# Best implementation for possbile event/occurance at any time: Usage of Thread/Timer?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

So i wrote a java program where the user can create several data sets. The data sets consist of a URL and a time.

Now the program's job is to permanently check if the current time is equal to one of the times saved in the data sets. If the current time appears to be the same time as one of the times defined in the data sets, a browser shall be opened with the URL saved in the data set of which the time has occured to be equal to the current time.

e.g "1.dataset: url="www.justexampleurl.com", time="24.12.2015 14:00"

Correctly executed, a browser with url "justexampleurl.com" would open when the current time hits 14 o'clock on the 24th of December, 2015.

**Question**: What is an efficient way to handle something like that? It seems like my program has to check the time e.g. every second, if the time is equal to one of the times of the datasets.
I was thinking about the need of a thread, since it has to run seperatly while the user still is able to create new datasets.

Can I use a timer/thread for this purpose or what are my possibilities?

Thanks a lot for your help, it is greatly appreciated since I have not written anything like that!

Comment: Start by studying the ScheduledExecutorService interface.

Comment: Also, see [Timer.schedule(TimerTask, Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-).

Comment: I looking into it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly polling to check & compare the time, why not just calculate the the difference between the future time & the current time, and `Thread.sleep()` until the the future time arrives? If you still want the user to be able to create new datasets while the timers are running, you can deploy a new thread for each additional dataset.

```
class MyTimerThread extends Thread {
    int seconds;
    String url;
    Thread(String url, int seconds) { 
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void run() {
        this.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        //Code to open browser...
    }
```

From your program's main execution...

```
public static void main() {
    while(true) {
        //Wait for user input (url, futureTime, currentTime)
        long secondsDifference = futureTime - currentTime; //Use unixtime
        (new MyTimerThread(url, secondsDifference)).start(); 
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a good approach to me, even though I am not familiar with using threads in programs yet. But how do I handle getting a new thread for a new created dataset and also relevant, deleting/disabling a thread after a dataset gets deleted?